# Rails JOIN TABLES

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm trying to use the GeoKit plugin to calculate the distance between 2 points. So the idea is, i do a search for an article, and the results i want to order by distance. So i have a form where I enter the article (that im looking for) and my address. Then rails must find all articles that match with my query and order by address.

So now, i have two models: Article and User. Articles belongs_to User and User has_many Articles. At the User model i have the info related with my latitude and longitude.

So my Article object has three fields:

- id
- name
- user_id (FK to User model)

And my user model has four fields

- id
- name
- lat (latitude)
- lng (longitude)

OK, to have access to the user info thru articles i do the query:

```
@articles = Article.find(:all,:conditions=>"vectors @@ to_tsquery('büch')",:joins=>" INNER JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id",:include=>:user,:origin=>"Augustusplatz,8,leipzig,germany")
```

it works. But when i wanna add an :order=>'distance ASC' it fails because the order by query is using a Article.lat, and Article.lng fields to calculate the distance, but these fields lat and lng, are User object's members and not Article member.

BTW if I get the query generated by rails and i change the order by clause where uses articles.lat/lng to users.lat/lng it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not really an SQL expert, and I find joins very hard to wrap my head around (even more than figuring out multiple NOT's like `if(!(foo != !bar & (!baz)))` ) but I do feel that either the `:joins` line or the `:include` line is redundant, or even wrong.

(I cleaned up your query so I could understand it, please do the same with the question):

```
@articles = Article.find(:all,
    :conditions=>"vectors @@ to_tsquery('büch')",
    :joins=>" INNER JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id",
    :include=>:user,
    :origin=>"Augustusplatz,8,leipzig,germany")
```

I guess either the model of the user and article should define their relation, so you don't need a manual join or that you remove the include.

But I don't see from this code where the distance is actually calculated (probably some automagic in GeoKit?). The distance should be "named" with the SQL someting like:

```
SELECT (some_heavy_calculation(user.lat, user.long)) AS distance, ... ;
```

So you can refer to the distance in the order by clause, I don't think the database cares if the *ruby* object doesn't contain the value.

Perhaps if you showed us the generated SQL, wich causes errors, and you'r manipulated SQL we could understand better...

Answer (score 1):

I didnt want to put the sql generated in the first post otherwise it would be too much thing :-)

I was using just include, that works, but i dont know why, include makes a left join, and i need a inner join. If i remove the include i cannot access the user information thru the article object (like for example articles[0].user.name)

here it is my sql. if i change in the order by the fields articles.lat and articles.lng to users.lat and user.lng it works:

```
SELECT "articles"."id" AS t0_r0, "articles"."name" AS t0_r1, "articles"."price" AS t0_r2, "articles"."user_id" AS t0_r3, "articles"."created_at" AS t0_r4, "articles"."updated_at" AS t0_r5, "articles"."vectors" AS t0_r6, "users_articles"."id" AS t1_r0, "users_articles"."name" AS t1_r1, "users_articles"."address" AS t1_r2, "users_articles"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "users_articles"."updated_at" AS t1_r4, "users_articles"."lat" AS t1_r5, "users_articles"."lng" AS t1_r6, "users_articles"."zipcode" AS t1_r7 FROM "articles"  LEFT OUTER JOIN "users" users_articles ON "users_articles".id = "articles".user_id     INNER JOIN users ON users.id = articles.user_id WHERE (vectors @@ to_tsquery('büch'))  ORDER BY                   (ACOS(least(1,COS(0.896021391737553)*COS(0.216084610510851)*COS(RADIANS(articles.lat))*COS(RADIANS(articles.lng))+
              COS(0.896021391737553)*SIN(0.216084610510851)*COS(RADIANS(articles.lat))*SIN(RADIANS(articles.lng))+
              SIN(0.896021391737553)*SIN(RADIANS(articles.lat))))*3963.19)
```

Regards,

Victor